# Bit slipping on pocket hole screw

Tags: woodworking, drill-bit

I have kreg #2 screws and i’m using the #2 square bit that it comes with. So I know the bit is not the problem. But when I drill and get less than half way in the bit starts slipping off the screw head. I don’t know what i’m doing wrong with the drill. I’m using softwood with clutch on 3. I have a 20V dewalt.

Comment: If the bit is old, your premise may be false. Or if you have a screw with crud in the head hole from manufacturing, the tapered square bit my not seat correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Check the bit for rounding.  If rounded get a new bit.

Check the fit of the bit with the screw head, it should be tight enough without any movement.

Keep pressure on the drill when driving the screw in.

Make pilot holes before driving the screw into the wood.

Comment: Just to add, having a near perfect angle (ie, 90°) is important. Don’t know how long the bit is, but sometimes using an extension will help line things up.